# How do I put a specific path where my script output could go?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I know this would be really easy for you but I am new in scripting. I would like to know how to put a specific path (a directory) where my script output (which is in .txt file) could go. I have this code which would create a .txt file ready to be placed in **/home/ubuntu/scriptoutput** directoy:

```
COUNTER=1

 while true; do
     FILENAME="HELLO($COUNTER).txt"
     if [ -e $FILENAME ]; then
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
     else
        break
     fi
done
(
printf "hello"
) > $FILENAME
```

Now the question is: Where do I puth the **/home/ubuntu/scriptoutput**? I hope you could help me.

Comment: do `./your_script.sh > /home/ubuntu/scriptoutput` or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I placed it in the script and it says /home/ubuntu/scriptoutput is a directory. I also tried to run it outside the script and it also says the same thing.

Comment: Then, redirect it to a  file :-) `./your_script.sh > /home/ubuntu/scriptoutput/log.txt`

Comment: You can use: `printf "hello\n" > "/home/ubuntu/scriptoutput/$FILENAME"`

Comment: Thanks guys. I replaced the `$FILENAME` at the end with `"/home/ubuntu/scriptoutput/$FILENAME"` and it now works like how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For the beginners who will also encounter this kind of problem:

```
COUNTER=1

 while true; do
     FILENAME="/home/ubuntu/scriptoutput/HELLO($COUNTER).txt"
     if [ -e $FILENAME ]; then
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
     else
        break
     fi
done
(
printf "hello"
) > $FILENAME
```

for those who answered, thank you so much :-)